# What is 'subdir' defined var in python 3 for all OS?

Tags: python, windows, unix, path, operating-system

I have a script in Python which i get 3 arguments from the user
One of the arguments is a folder path in which there are some files i need to use
Since my program is designed for all OS, i would like to know how to use the path from the   argument correctly to get to my required files
I.E.
if i get the following path :

```
c:\windows
```

i would like to be able to get 1.exe in this folder,
In windows it will be slash or backslash but in unix systems it will be probably different,
As i understand there is a const or defined var from 'os' module in which i can use as this subdir sign, where can i find it  ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `os.path.join` and Python will take care of the slash for you:

```
path = os.path.join(sys.argv[1], '1.exe')
```

The platform-specific path separator is stored as `os.sep`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `os.path.join()`.  For example:

```
os.path.join(dirname, "1.exe")
```